# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() Беда прям

Tags: php, foreach

Работал скрипт работал и вдруг стал ругаться на вот эту строку `foreach($rows as $row)`.
Cам код :

```
ini_set('allow_url_fopen', '1');
set_time_limit(0);
require_once('simplehtmldom/simple_html_dom.php');
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "parser", "parser", "parser");
$query = "SELECT id, linkdns FROM parser WHERE pricedns = 0";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $Id = $row['id'];
    $Link = $row['linkdns'];
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, trim($Link));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://yandex.ru');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__) . '/dns_cookie.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, dirname(__FILE__) . '/dns_cookie.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla Firefox 3 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; LAS Linux)");
    $contents = curl_exec($ch);
    $Html = str_get_html($contents);
    curl_close($ch);
    $Html = @str_get_html($contents);//получаем страницу
    if ($Html->find('a[class="ec-price-item-link"]', 0)) {
        $Item1 = $Html->find('a[class="ec-price-item-link"]', 0);
        @$Item = $Html->href;
    } else {
        $Item = 55555555;//ищем нужный тэг
    }
    $Html->clear(); // подчищаем за собой
    unset($Html);//снимаем заявленную переменную
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE parser SET itemdns = ? WHERE id = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $Item, $Id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
}
header('Refresh: 5; url=dns4.php');
```

Comment: Дупликатов море, если честно http://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=Invalid+argument+supplied+for+foreach%28%29    пустой у вас `$rows` значит.... Не массив

Comment: @АлексейШиманский пустой не выкинит ошибки а вот true или false это да

Comment: var_dump($rows);die; сделайте перед foreach;

Comment: и перед while объявите массив `$rows = array()`

Comment: Thank's guy's ... Помогло вот это --- $rows = array() !!!